# extracting data from list

Tags: python

I have a list:

```
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'18018 - CARPEAUX': 2, '12009 - DIDEROT': 2, '21003 - JAURES 1 (BOULOGNE-BILLANCOURT)': 7, '11041 - SAINT AMBROISE': 6, '15006 - CHERCHE MIDI': 6, '12035 - MADAGASCAR': 6, '08549 - PLACE DUNANT': 1, '21002 - DENFERT ROCHEREAU (BOULOGNE-BILLANCOURT)': 4, '07013- PLACE DE BRETEUIL': 5, '14019 - SARETTE GENERAL LECLERC': 2, '10041 - CHARTRES (18 ARR.)': 2, '12029 - DUGOMMIER': 14, '08038 - FRANCOIS 1 ER': 0, '15063 - SAINT CHARLES - CONVENTION': 0, '21105 - MORICE (CLICHY)': 2, '10113 - PARMENTIER LOUVEL-TESSIER': 8, '21503 - LEDRU ROLLIN (SURESNES)': 0, '15021 - CROIX NIVERT': 7, '18043 -BLANCHE': 4, '150)...)
```

but I just want a list with the numbers 2,2 .... so for ...'18018 - CARPEAUX': 2, ... I just want the number 2. How can I do that ?

Comment: You have a `dictionary` and if you are looking to get the values, then just call `.values()` on that defaultdict object.

Comment: Which is it, Java or Python? Those tags can't both apply.

Comment: ...Is this Java?? It looks like no Java I've ever seen.

Comment: It is definitely Python, so I'm not sure why `java` was tagged.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and follow the guidelines there to refine your question with additional information, such as code and error message to describe your programming problem.

Comment: That's not a list. As it says, it's a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict). This isn't simply a theoretical difference; lists are quite different from all forms of dicts.

Comment: You need to post code in a format so we can paste it into our editors. This is riddled with syntax errors.

Comment: @rosh, that's not Python source code. It's the way `defaultdict`s are `__repr__()`'d.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a `list`, you have a `defaultdict`. So just do `varname.values()` and it will get you the values.

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> a = defaultdict()
>>> a[1] = 2
>>> a
defaultdict(None, {1: 2})
>>> a.values()
dict_values([2])
```

To get it into a `list`:

```
>> list(a.values())
[2]
```